# Accessing the last character of a specific element in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am currently building something like a flash card programme to help me learn both french and python at the same time using pandas and numpy.

I have a csv with 3 columns which i convert to a dataframe (verbs). My code randomly selects a row (selection) and gives a word in french, then the user has to input the past tense version of that word (which is found in the third column of the dataframe/csv). I have got this part working so far.

I'm trying to add in a 'hint' function whereby the user inputs the word 'hint' and it will give the last letter of the correct answer from column 3 of the selection dataframe.

I can't seem to figure out how to access the last letter of the third column however.

Below is an isolated part where I am simply trying to get it to print the last character of row 0 column 2 from the dataframe 'selection'

```
verbs=pd.read_csv('u_participle.csv')
selection=(verbs.sample())
print(selection.iloc[0,2].str[-1:])
```

This gives error:
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'**

Am I close here or am I completely barking up the wrong tree with the last line?

I've look all over and the answers are generally quite specific/ my knowledge of python isn't quite good enough to understand the answers

Comment: Can you try this and update ```print(selection.iloc[0,2][-1])```

Comment: Always share the entire error message. Do you not have a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

In Python (and in general), strings are treated as arrays. So to access the last entry in a string, you only need to type [-1]. [0]. In addition, to access a single character, you just need a single digit i.e. [-1], and not a list which is what you've tried to do [-1:].

E.g.

given:

`x = "Name"`

```
x[0] will equal 'N'
x[-1] will equal 'e'
x[1:-1] will equal 'ame'
```

And so, all you should to do is change your code to:

```
verbs=pd.read_csv('u_participle.csv')
selection=(verbs.sample())
print(selection.iloc[0,2][-1])
```

See if that works!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I was overcomplicating things

Comment: @Aidan basically `.iloc[0, 2]` gives you the actual object at that position which in this case is a `str` so you can treat it exactly like you would a string... Where you need to use the `str` accessor is if you wanted to get the last character for everything in the column... eg: `.iloc[:, 2].str[-1]`